# incremental bundles of git repositories

Tags: bash, git

I am creating incremental bundles of my git repository using:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -f ./source0.bundle ]; then
    git bundle create source0.bundle --all
elif [ $(git rev-parse HEAD) != $(git bundle list-heads source0.bundle | head -1 | cut -d' ' -f1) ]; then
    declare -i LARGEST_NUMBER=$(ls | grep "source.*\.bundle" | tail -1 | grep -o '[0-9]*')
    LARGEST_NUMBER_PLUS_ONE=$((LARGEST_NUMBER+1))

    git bundle create source${LARGEST_NUMBER_PLUS_ONE}.bundle $(git bundle list-heads source${LARGEST_NUMBER}.bundle | head -1 | cut -d' ' -f1)..HEAD
fi
```

It creates `source0.bundle`, `source1.bundle`, `source2.bundle`....

To restore the bundles, I have to run:

```
$ git clone source0.bundle extract
$ cd extract
$ for ((i = 1 ; i < 3 ; i++ )); do git pull ../source${i}.bundle; done
```

Is this a good approach or am i complicating things?

Comment: Good *for what purpose?*

Comment: What is a git bundle ?!

Comment: @torek sorry for the delayed response. It is to backup my repository in a single file. like zip the .git folder.

Comment: You can use a bundle as a Git backup file, but that's not really its main intended use: the point of `git bundle` is to be able to implement `git fetch` over air-gapped networks and the like. If you make the bundle as a file that contains every commit (a single initial "everything" bundle), you get a file that works as a backup. But it's more typical to just have a backup repository somewhere, and use `git push` or `git fetch` or `git clone` to make more backups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

man git-bundle

> DESCRIPTION
> Create, unpack, and manipulate "bundle" files. Bundles are used for the "offline" transfer of Git objects without an active "server" sitting on the other side of the network connection.

This is the first time I hear about git bundles. If you need to maintain a copy of your repository somewhere, you can create a remote to a local folder like:

```
git remote add secondary /backup/foo/bar.git
```

Then you can push to this remote.

```
git push secondary master
```

There are some quirks, such as not being able to push to a checked-out remote, but you can make it a "bare" remote as in a "server" remote.

```
git init --bare /backup/foo/bar.git
```

Pushing to a bare repository is same as pushing to github or bitbucket.

In my opinion, you don't need bundles unless you know you do. If in doubt, you don't need them.